Making C# transformation using gdal referencing python-based pyproj
Recently, I have been migrating code from python to c#. One of the things that is necessary is for coordinate transformations of large amounts of data. The python script looks like the following:
latitude = centerlat
longitude = centerlon

x = radardata['range'] * np.sin(np.deg2rad(radardata['azimuths'][sweep]))[:,None]
y = radardata['range'] * np.cos(np.deg2rad(radardata['azimuths'][sweep]))[:,None]

dataproj = Proj(f"+proj=eqc +lat_0={latitude} +lat_ts={latitude} +lon_0={longitude} +ellps=WGS84 +units=m")
lons,lats = dataproj(x,y,inverse=True)

in which we convert polar data to cartesian (x, y) and then convert these to an eqc projection.
I have gdal working in C#:
double latitude = data.Latitude;
double longitude = data.Longitude;

// Setup our spatial information
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
Gdal.AllRegister();
Ogr.RegisterAll();

// What projection are we going from?
SpatialReference src = new SpatialReference("");
src.ImportFromProj4("+proj=latlon + datum=WGS84 +no_defs");

// Generate the string that includes out latitude and longitude information
var stringy = "+proj=eqc +lat_0=" + data.Latitude.ToString() + " +lat_ts=" + data.Latitude.ToString() + " +lon_0=" + data.Longitude.ToString() + " +ellps=WGS84 +units=m";

// What projection are we going to?
SpatialReference dst = new SpatialReference("");
dst.ImportFromProj4(stringy);

// Making the transformation
CoordinateTransformation ct = new CoordinateTransformation(src, dst);

for (int i = 0; i < data.AzimuthSize;i++)
for (int j = 0; j < data.RangeSize; j++)
{
    x[i, j] = centerGate[j] * Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * data.Azimuth[i]);
    y[i, j] = centerGate[j] * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * data.Azimuth[i]);
}

// Now we have values for x and y. We need to implement the conversion
var eqcLats = new double[data.AzimuthSize, data.RangeSize];
var eqcLons = new double[data.AzimuthSize, data.RangeSize];

// Do the transformations
for (int i = 0; i < data.AzimuthSize; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < data.RangeSize; j++)
{
    double[] p = new double[2];
    p[0] = y[i, j];
    p[1] = x[i, j];
    ct.TransformPoint(p);

    eqcLats[i, j] = p[0];
    eqcLons[i, j] = p[1]
}


The problem is that an error at ct.TransformPoint occurs because x > 90 (invalid latitude) in the C# code. However, this is not an issue in the python code. Therefore, I seem to be overlooking something. Someone with experience might be able to pinpoint rather quickly what the issue seems to be.
